# The Symfony FormType contains 1 abstract method after update to 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I just recently updated to 2.8 and now I get the following error when calling the create function of the Form Factory.

```
Error: Class Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType contains 1 
abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the 
remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::setDefaultOptions)
```

The call of the FormFactory looks like this:

```
$this->formFactory->create(
        get_class(new ProductType()),
        $product,
        [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'type' => $type,
            'locales' => $context->shop->getLocales(),
            'product' => $product,
            'numberDataTransformer' => $this->numberTransformerFactory->createFromLocale(
                $context->user->getLocale(),
                $context->shop->getDefaultLocale()
            ),
            'priceType' => $context->shop->getConfiguration()->getProductConfiguration()->getPricesBackend(),
            'isShortDescriptionEnabled' => $context->shop->getConfiguration()->getProductConfiguration()->isShortDescriptionEnabled()
        ]);
```

I tried several ways to pass the ProductType to the function, but none seems to work. I always get one out of two results: Either the result is that the type cannot be found or the error is returned that the FormType does not implement setDefaultOptions.

What did I miss?

EDIT:

Here are some additional code:

The declaration of the formFactory parameter:

```
public function __construct(Request $request, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory)
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
}
```

The ProductType class

```
<?php

namespace CustomNamespace\BackendBundle\Product\Form;

use CustomNamespace\BackendBundle\Common\NumberDataTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use CustomNamespace\BackendBundle\Product\Form\ImageType;
use ShopwareEasy\BackendBundle\Product\Form\AttachmentType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\InvalidOptionsException;

/**
 * Form element type for products.
 */
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $method;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $locales;

    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var \CustomNamespace\BackendBundle\Common\NumberDataTransformer
     */
    private $numberDataTransformer;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $priceType;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $isShortDescriptionEnabled;

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->setMethod($this->method);
        $regionType = new RegionShippingTimeType();

        if ($this->type == 'download') {
            $regionType->enableForDownloadableProduct();
        }

        $builder->add('regions', 'collection', array(
            'type'   => $regionType,
            'label' => false,
            'options'  => array(
                'required'  => false,
                'attr'      => array('class' => 'email-box')
            ),
        ));

        $builder->add('vendor', 'text', ['label' => 'form_product_vendor']);
        if ($this->type == 'normal') {
            $builder->add(
                'mainVariant',
                new MainVariantNormalType(
                    $this->method,
                    $this->locales,
                    $this->product,
                    $this->numberDataTransformer,
                    $this->priceType,
                    $this->isShortDescriptionEnabled
                ),
                ['error_bubbling' => false, 'label' => false]
            );
        } elseif ($this->type == 'download') {
            $builder->add(
                'mainVariant',
                new MainVariantDownloadType(
                    $this->method,
                    $this->locales,
                    $this->product,
                    $this->numberDataTransformer,
                    $this->priceType,
                    $this->isShortDescriptionEnabled
                ),
                ['error_bubbling' => false, 'label' => false]
            );
        } elseif ($this->type == 'variant') {
            $builder->add(
                'mainVariant',
                new MainVariantVariantType(
                    $this->method,
                    $this->locales,
                    $this->product,
                    $this->numberDataTransformer,
                    $this->priceType,
                    $this->isShortDescriptionEnabled
                ),
                ['error_bubbling' => false, 'label' => false]
            );
        }

        if ($this->method == 'PUT') {
            $builder->add(
                'images',
                new ImageType(),
                ['error_bubbling' => true, 'label' => false]
            );

            $builder->add(
                'attachments',
                new AttachmentType(),
                ['error_bubbling' => true, 'label' => false]
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'CustomNamespace\\BackendBundle\\Product\\Product',
                'csrf_protection' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'method' => 'POST',
                'type' => 'normal'
            )
        );

        parent::configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        /** @var OptionResolver $resolver */
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    public function getName() {
        return get_class($this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide us with more code.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov What else do you need? Thats the single important spot. I guess its not necessary to post the symfony 2.8 code in here ;)

Comment: Post here your `ProductType` code. What is in your `$this->formFactory`? Where did you load it?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I added the ProductType class. The Factory is an implementation of the FormFactoryInterface, dumping the FQCN shows me that it is symfonies standard FormFactory

Comment: Why do you not want to use normal names? Why do you want this Symfony3-like style? Make typical name `product` and use it.

Comment: Is get_class(new ProductType()) returning the expected fqcn?  The error message is complaining about FormType and not ProductType.  Try replacing it with the actual string per the example in the book or ProductType::class

Comment: also you don't need to use `setDefaultOptions` while you implement `configureOptions`

Comment: @Cerad It is returning the right FQCN. The problem is: in the process of creating the Builder, symfony tries to create the FormType because it is a parent of the AbstractType - but the FormType can't be created because one abstract method is not implemented.

What I wonder about: How can this only occur in my case? I can see why this error is thrown and this code is in the git repository. But I think that a lot more people would complain about this if it is a general problem...

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I implemented it for BC. If some old component tries to call setDefaultOptions, it is still possible.

Comment: It is not general problem. Your error is about `FormType`, not about `ProductType` and so it occurs. You need to pass to your factory normal name. Why do you not want to use normal names? And about BC: if you already have Symfony 2.8 and your `ProductType` implements new interface it will always depends on Symfony 2.8. And so any old component that use your form do it via Symfony Forms component that is already 2.8 and so your "BC" method will never be used.

Comment: Try removing the `getName()` method from the form type. You don't need it anymore. Also, instantiating an object to get a class namespace is really odd and wasteful. I'd just use `ProductType::class`.

Comment: what is the code for Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType?

Comment: FormType extends BaseType which in turn extends AbstractType.  So FormType is not a parent ot ProductType at all.  Something in your code is making it try to create a FormType instead of ProductType.  It's all very strange.  Maybe try to clear all the caches and even delete the vendor directory and do a complete reinstall.  Heck, even a reboot just to make sure the apc is not messing with you.

Comment: I think the problem might be all the other Types being created inside of ProductType using the old 2.7 style.  You also have quite a bit of other stuff inside of ProductType.  Try commenting everything out and see what happens.

Comment: @Cerad FormType is not a parent ot ProductType, but it is using. Type hierarchy is defined by method getParent(), not only by class  hierarchy.

Comment: Not seeing a getParent in your posted code.  In any event, you have too much stuff in there for me to see what is happening.  Good luck.

Comment: Remove `setDefaultOptions()`, change `configureOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)` to say `public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)`, and get rid of the `parent::configureOptions($resolver);` call

Answer (score 0):

The problem was produced by files that were not updated at all.. The implementation of setDefaultOptions should still exist in the Symfony 2.8 classes - but they didn't.
After destroying my vagrant and recreating it again, everything worked just fine.

But thanks everyone for the help!